# Shapely: intersection point between line and polygon in 3D

Tags: python, vector, geometry, shapely

Last time I used shapely, I really had [this nice import-and-fly-feeling](https://www.xkcd.com/353/).
However recently, I run into a rather non-intuitive behavior in this module, as I tried to find the intersection between a line segment and a triangle in 3D space. Let's define a segment and a triangle as follow:

```
l = LineString([[1,0.5,0.5],[3,0.5,0.5]])
p = Polygon([[1.2,0.0,0.],[2.2,1.0,0.],[2.8,0.5,1.]])
```

To get their point of intersection I used `l.intersection(p)`, and expected a point, namely `POINT Z (POINT Z (2 0.5 0.25))`. It is illustrated with the blue dot below:

[image]

Instead what I got was `LINESTRING Z (1.7 0.5 0.25, 2.8 0.5 1)` - red line below - and frankly I am quite perplexed about what it is supposed to represent.
[image]

Oddly enough, when the polygon/triangle is in the xz-plane and orthogonal to the line segment, the function behaves as one would expect. When the triangle is "leaning", however, it returns a line. This has temporarily lead me to believe that it returned the intersection between the line and the triangle's bounding box. The above red line proves otherwise.

So a workaround for this problem has been to read [this very enlightening web-page](http://geomalgorithms.com/a05-_intersect-1.html), and adapt their `C++` code to work with shapely objects. The `intersection` method works great to check whether the line goes through the polygon, and the function below finds the point of interest.

```
def intersect3D_SegmentPlane(Segment, Plane):

    # Points in Segment: Pn  Points in Plane: Qn
    P0, P1     = np.array(Segment.coords)
    Q0, Q1, Q2 = np.array(Plane.exterior)[:-1]   

    # vectors in Plane
    q1 = Q1 - Q0
    q2 = Q2 - Q0

    # vector normal to Plane
    n  = np.cross(q1, q2)/np.linalg.norm(np.cross(q1, q2))
    u = P1 - P0 # Segment's direction vector 
    w = P0 - Q0 # vector from plane ref point to segment ref point

    ## Tests parallelism
    if np.dot(n, u) == 0:
        print "Segment and plane are parallel"
        print "Either Segment is entirely in Plane or they never intersect."
        return None
    ## if intersection is a point
    else:
        ## Si is the scalar where P(Si) = P0 + Si*u lies in Plane
        Si = np.dot(-n, w) / np.dot(n, u)
        PSi = P0 + Si * u
        return PSi
```

Not very import-and-fly anymore...

So finally to my questions:

- What does `intersection` return when applied to 3D-objects and why is it a line?
- Is there a function in shapely that does what I want? or any optional argument, tweak or dark magic trick?
- Is there any other libraries out there that would do this job while fulfilling my dreams of simplicity and laziness?

Answer (score 7):

unfortunately, as the documentation states:

> Coordinate sequences are immutable. A third z coordinate value may be used when constructing instances, but has no effect on geometric analysis. All operations are performed in the x-y plane.

One can verify this with:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon

l = LineString([[1,0.5,0.5],[3,0.5,0.5]])
p = Polygon([[1.2,0.0,0.],[2.2,1.0,0.],[2.8,0.5,1.]])
print(l.intersection(p))
#LINESTRING Z (1.7 0.5 0.25, 2.8 0.5 1)

l = LineString([[1,0.5],[3,0.5]])
p = Polygon([[1.2,0.0],[2.2,1.0],[2.8,0.5]])
print(l.intersection(p))
#LINESTRING (1.7 0.5, 2.8 0.5)
```

or even:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon

l = LineString([[1,0.5,0],[3,0.5,0]])
p = Polygon([[1.2,0.0,1],[2.2,1.0,1],[2.8,0.5,1]])
print(l.intersects(p))
#True (even though the objects are in different z-planes)
```

Comment: It's 2022 now and this answer is still valid :-(